# HttpPost ActionResult Edit() does not update all attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

When I change all attributes in the Edit view and then hit "Save", the database only updates all simple attributes like integers and strings.
However, my model is a "User" and a user has one "Permission" and can have multiple "Roles". These are classes too and they just won't change with the update.

I'm using this UserViewModel (strongly typed to the edit view):

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    AuditDB db = new AuditDB();

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for an empty userviewmodel, without a user
    /// </summary>
    public UserViewModel()
    {
        AllRoles = db.Roles.ToList();
        UserRoles = new List<Role>();
        User = new User();
        User.Roles = new List<Role>();
        SelectedRoleIds = UserRoles.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for a userviewmodel with an already existing user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userId"></param>
    public UserViewModel(int userId)
    {
        AllRoles = db.Roles.ToList();
        User = db.Users.Single(user => user.Id == userId);
        UserRoles = User.Roles.ToList();
        SelectedRoleIds = UserRoles.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();
    }


    public User User { get; set; }
    public List<Role> AllRoles { get; set; }
    public List<Role> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public int[] SelectedRoleIds { get; set; }
}
```

The controller (where I think the error lies) looks like that:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            model.User.Permission = db.Permissions.Single(p => p.Id == model.User.Permission.Id);
            model.User.Roles = new List<Role>();
            foreach (int roleId in model.SelectedRoleIds)
            {
                model.User.Roles.Add(db.Roles.Single(role => role.Id == roleId));
            }
            model.User.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;
            db.Entry(model.User).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(model);
    }
```

Bonus Question on the side: I instantiate my AuditDB (:DbContext) class in my UserViewModel to access a list of all Roles from there. Is this the right place to put that or shouldn't I do this in a ViewModel?

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Comment: Database access code does not belong in your view model. That's the responsibility of the controller.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I created static methods in my controller now which return stuff like AllRoles... I think it looks cleaner like this but didnt solve the issue though :/

Comment: I wonder how simple properties are saved, cause you don't attach the User entity to the DbContext in the Edit method. I thing you have to explicitly load the entity from the context, using methods Include and Single, then you can change its properties together with related entities, and such entity should be saved correctly.

Comment: Well in the HttpGet method I load the user from the db with Single but in HttpPost the whole model has already changed and I need to save these changes. Wouldn't it be pointless to load the old state again?